# How to Call MATERIAL ICONS ROUNDED VERSION ON REACT NATIVE

Tags: react-native, google-material-icons, material-icons

-I'm new on react native and I need used on the project MaterialIcons but the rounded version. I'm searching on the documentation but I have no clue how to apply it, only render the filled regular version. Can someone help me and tell me if I can use it? Thanks! This is what I have [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ls35F.png)

**Note: I tried with some borderRadius styling and doesn't not working

```
import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

  return <MaterialIcons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
```

And this is what I need as a result [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXImF.png)